# Create functionality like Google Translate chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome extension, I need the following functionality when the user selects some word in the browser page, I want to trigger an event, that is simple, it is very like the Google Translate Google Chrome extension, which shows popup when selecting word.

I have tried the following

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, callback) {
    if (message.data == "getSelection")
        console.log(message.data);
});
```

manifest

```
{

"permissions": [ "activeTab", "<all_urls>", "declarativeContent", "storage" ],
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "images/cdicon.png"
  }
},
"background": {
  "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
  "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
    "js": [ "selection.js" ],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true
  }
]
}
```

the problem is that there is no event triggered when selecting any word

Comment: Sounds like you need document.addEventListener('selectionchange', yourcallback)

Comment: @wOxxOm ok where to put that? in the background.js ?

Comment: Only content scripts can access web pages, see the [architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) article.

Comment: `selection.js` is your content script you can put `document.addEventListener('selectionchange', yourcallback) ` in that file.